# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}/ \equiv 3$ has exactly three elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

The Definition: Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on the set $A$. The set of all equivalence classes is
denoted by $A/R$.

The hint I have been given: First, verify that $[5]_3$, $[7]_3$, and $[0]_3$ are three different elements of $\mathbb{Z}/ \equiv 3$. Then, verify
that every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is in one of these sets. Then explain why those two facts imply that $[5]_3$, $[7]_3$,
and $[0]_3$ are the only elements of $\mathbb{Z}/ \equiv 3$.

I am lost to how I should approach this problem or better yet how I should verify that "$[5]_3$, $[7]_3$, and $[0]_3$ are three different elements of $\mathbb{Z}/ \equiv 3$". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start might be by carefully writing down what it means for two integers to be equivalent with respect to the equivalence relation $\equiv 3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it more generally. Prove that, when $n>0$,

> $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ if and only if the remainder of the division of $a$ and $b$ by $n$ is the same.

With this at hand, we're almost done, after noticing that, by definition, $a$ is congruent modulo $n$ to the remainder of the division of $a$ by $n$.

Since the remainders are elements in $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ and each integer is congruent to *exactly* one of these, the number of equivalence classes is $n$. Note that each one of these actually appears as a remainder, namely of the division of itself by $n$.

Comment: You forgot: "... and since each of $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ actually appears as a remainder". Empty sets are not equivalence classes :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg That's obvious, but I'll add it anyway.

Comment: Yep, but everything here is obvious in a way :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg The equivalence I mentioned is not always emphasized; in my opinion it should: having two descriptions of the relation makes it possible to work with it in more ways.

Answer (score 0):

$[0]_3$ and $[1]_3=[7]_3$ and $[2]_3=[5]_3$ are the only elements of $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ since $[x]_3=[x\text{ mod }3]_3$.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $\mathbb Z/\equiv 3$ are *equivalence classes*. That is, $$[k]=\{x| x\equiv k\pmod 3\}$$

As these classes are actually sets, you can prove that $[5]\neq [3]$ simply by showing that there is SOME element that is in $[5]$ (for example, $5\in[5]$) which is not in $[3]$.

To prove that the elements you list are the *only* elements, first show that $[5]=[2]$ and $[7]=[1]$, and then show that $[0]\cup[1]\cup[2]=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Induction is the key!

Start with the inductive step:

$[0]_3,[1]_3,[2]_3$ are different classes. Now, assume that $[k]_3,[k+1]_3,[k+2]_3$ are the only classes. What can you tell me about $k+3$?